# jQMobi documentation mirror

Tags: jqmobi

Just got started and running with jqMobi, which is now called 'intel's application framework' (cheesy name eh) 
Along with intel's porting to their new site, they forgot to put the full docs online (at least I can't find it). Now there's only minimal documentation, like the getting started. I'd like to get on with it.

Anyone knows where the (full) docs are hosted? I really hate to go look for another framework again.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is all there.  The only thing they did not add was the "testdrive", which is just the kitchen sink sample found in github

Comment: The question was where. If you say 'The documentation is all there' then please prove it with a link. I know these links: 'http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php?r=9057', but they lead to nothing but getting started stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the docs are somewhat scattered, but there's some helpful stuff if you can find it.  I keep bookmarks for these links.  There are some links from those that get you to more stuff.

http://html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/jqmobiapis/index.html

http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php?r=9057

http://developer.html5dev-software.intel.com/

http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/

Actually they split off where appMobi is a cloud services company to support apps, and Intel took the part to build the apps.  So you may still need/want appMobi.  Their docs are on their site of course.  There is still some duplication on the appMobi site.

Technically I don't think jqMobi is the same thing as the Intel App Framework, but at the same time I have a hard time understanding what's called what anymore.  I'm sure they'll clear this up over time.  I hope they find names that can be useful tags on stackoverflow.com!

Comment: App Framework *is* jqMobi - Intel bought the assets (and hired me, the developer).

We are working on the transition still and hope to have better documentation and community support!

Comment: Thanks, but all the links merely lead to the same page. Where the link says full documentation, but after clicking on it, you only go to the getting started stuff. For example: http://html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/jqmobiapis/index.html leads to: http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php?r=9057, which is the getting started manual.

Comment: I beg to differ.  Check all the links. Look around a little bit on those links.

Comment: I think the most important thing is the kitchensink which used to be under jqmobi.com/testdrive - anybody knows where it can be found online? Otherwise @user258082 (Ian?) - may be good if you could give the other intel folks a poke to put these online again...